# Find PDF of a Random Variable using two Random Variables using the Laplace Transform

Tags: probability, statistics, multivariable-calculus, random-variables, laplace-transform

The specific problem I need to answer is

"Let X and Y be independent Exp(1) random variables. Determine the pdf of U =
X/(X + Y )."

I know that my goal is to find the CDF of U (then differentiate) by describing {U<=u}.

I have seen examples where Y = X^2 or even Z = X + Y. However, the calculus required is apparently too difficult for the stat course I'm taking, so we're using transforms. In this case the laplace transform because our variables are continuous.

We know that if I have L(X) and L(Y) (easily found) that X + Y = L(X)*L(Y), but I have no idea how the transform translates to dividing random variables? I'm finding it hard to google this question, and I'm on school break right now so I'm asking it on here :)

So that's my question, or, an explanation about why the question I'm asking is stupid would also be helpful, really any googleable methods would be helpful, thanks

**[no full solutions please!]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** for any $t\in(0,1)$,
$$\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\leq t\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{Y}{X}}\leq t\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{Y}{X}\geq\frac{1}{t}-1\right]$$
and for any $\rho>0$
$$\mathbb{P}[Y\geq \rho X] =\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\int_{\rho x}^{+\infty}e^{-y}\,dy\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(\rho+1)x}\,dx=\frac{1}{\rho+1}$$
hence for any $t\in(0,1)$ we have 
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\leq t\right]= t $$
and $U=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ has a **u**niform distribution over $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but not totally sure how this helps. As U is going to be defined from 0 to infinity like X and Y (as exp variables). Also, as U = X/X+Y From what you said, P(U<=u) = u. Which means the CDF of U is u, and the pdf of U is 1 over the range 0 to 1? Which I don't think is true? Just wondering what the next step here might be, I get that P[(X/X+Y) <= t] = t helps describe the CDF of U, but as above, it doesn't make much sense to me that that is what it would be

Comment: @DylanKidd: since X and X+Y are positive variables, their ratio is at most 1, hence the PDF of U is supported on (0,1).

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. For some reason I had to run it in matlab before I was convinced. 
So if U is a uniform distribution over (0,1) and isn't defined anywhere else.... isn't _that_ the pdf? 
i.e. U ~ Uniform(0,1)? Or U(x) = 1 0<x<1, 0 otherwise?

Also, I note that P(Y>=pX) is the same as the laplace transform of X or Y. Moving from your 2nd line to your 3rd, did you sub 1/p+1 as t there to get that the probability = t?

Comment: @DylanKidd: the PDF of $U=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ is the function that equals one just over the interval $(0,1)$ (or $(0,1]$ or $[0,1)$ or $[0,1]$, it does not really matter).